# Trying to find the smallest sums comprised of n contiguous values in an array

Tags: python

```
ar = [15,10,20,5,7,9,35,77]

def smallestSubArraySizeN(array, n):
    current_smallest = 9000
    unf = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(array)-n):

        while unf < n:
            sum += array[i+unf]
            unf += 1
        if sum < current_smallest:
            current_smallest = sum
        else:
            sum = sum-array[i]
        unf = 0
    print("thisis" , current_smallest)
    return current_smallest


a = smallestSubArraySizeN(ar,3)
```

So here I would expect to get 5+7+9 = 21 but when I run this I am getting 45. I am wondering where my logic fails, if anyone has any ideas, thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't shadow 'built-in' `sum` please 

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're doing a lot of work. Rather you can use a generator expression to create a sequence of list slices to sum, and then find the min of those sums.

```
def smallest_sum(lst, n):
    return min(sum(lst[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(lst) - n + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

- *Always* remove the first value from the sum.
- When you do, decrease `unf` by 1, don't set it to 0.
- Add +1 to the range so you don't miss the last value/sum.

```
ar = [15,10,20,5,7,9,35,77]

def smallestSubArraySizeN(array, n):
    current_smallest = 9000
    unf = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(array)-n+1):

        while unf < n:
            sum += array[i+unf]
            unf += 1
        if sum < current_smallest:
            current_smallest = sum
        sum = sum-array[i]
        unf -= 1
    print("thisis" , current_smallest)
    return current_smallest


a = smallestSubArraySizeN(ar,3)
```

Comment: thank you kelly this is exactly what I was looking for in terms of an answer that showed me exactly what I failed to in order to have my approach working. Thanks a lot, did a lot to teach me, have a good one. Oh right of course unf needs to be decreased by just one instead of going to zero, that was tricky to catch

Answer (score 0):

This approach seems a little too complex. You can use a sliding window instead.

You shouldn't use `sum()` inside a generator comprehension; it's not worth the extra conciseness. You'll recompute the sum over (roughly) the same numbers over and over again, meaning that the complexity can be quadratic in the size of the array in the worst case. This will always run in linear time, as it's a one pass algorithm:

```py
from math import inf
def smallestSubArraySizeN(array, n):
    smallest_total = current_total =  sum(array[:n])
    for idx in range(n, len(array)):
        current_total += array[idx] - array[idx - n]
        smallest_total = min(current_total, smallest_total)
    
    return smallest_total
```

For the given input, this outputs:

```py
21
```

Comment: yeah I suppose that's what I was tying to do. I just want to be able to solve it my own way without the internet this way I put my own brain to use and learn more. But, my while statement will only run n times, so 3 times N iterations in the for loop is still linear in time complexity so it should be about the same right? Also, I see your solution it's nice but do you know where mine screws up?

Comment: Not immediately sure, but the control flow is more complex than it needs to be. Maybe see Kelly Bundy's answer?

Comment: got it, thank you lots as well broken